# Unlocking (Xiaomi) Redmi 9A without a Windows PC

Tags: xiaomi, bootloader-lock, redmi

Xiaomi provides a tool for unlocking their phones called "Mi Unlock" but only runs on a Windows PC. I only have access to Mac (both Intel and ARM64) and Linux. I don't have Windows.

I already enabled USB Debugging and OEM Unlocking. I can get the device with `fastboot devices` but almost no other fastboot command works.

So what are my options?

- Can Mi Unlock work on an emulator like VirtualBox? If so, what is the recommended Windows version?
- Does anyone know if Xiaomi has a Linux source or binary of the Mi Unlock tool?
- Also, does anyone know why Android Platform Tools don't work? Why can't I just use the command line `fastboot oem unlock`, instead of their specific app?

Comment: To my experience USB connections from within virtual environments don't work reliable for low-level phone tools (because of timing and other side-effects when USB device disappear and reappear e.g. because of a phone reboot) .Or even worse increase the risk of bricking the phone, depending on how risky the operation is.

Comment: https://github.com/Canny1913/miunlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a bit advertising, but the next best tool for unlocking Xiaomi phones along with Official [Mi Unlock](https://en.miui.com/unlock/download_en.html) is that Unofficial [XiaoMiTool V2](https://github.com/francescotescari/XiaoMiToolV2/releases). It can run on Windows, Linux and Mac OS. XMT2 comes with built in bootloader unlock tool. Works the same as the official one.

[image]

Comment: On macOS arm64 it was a bit unstable (suspect it runs w/ Rosetta). Then I installed on Linux and everything works fine until the unlock step. Then it gets stuck on "Failed to get the device unlock token" Error origin: com.xiaomitool.v2.procedure.install.Fastbootinstall$4.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: you have to enable Xiaomi Cloud syncs + Find device, Xiaomi SIM Activation Service, bond sim card in Settings - Mi Account, and enable mi unlock status in developer options, then wait for 7 days, enter fastboot and use the mi account for unlocking

Comment: Thank you so much for all the great info ! I performed all those steps and waiting the 7 days. I will follow up on this thread to see how it goes...

Comment: It's day 8 and the same problem persists. "Failed to get the device unlock token" Error family code: info_retrieve_failed. Then it shows the class that generated the exception: FastbootInstall$4.run(Unknown Source).